# Very basic modular example

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This is a very basic question, but I cannot get it right. I'm working on a basic asymmetric encryption example.

So $(m^e)^d  \equiv m \pmod n$
(at least with the premise of m < n, I suppose)

If I choose:

- m = 14   (my message)
- n = 19
- e = 3
- d = 13  -- because $3 \cdot 13 ≡ 1 \pmod{19}$

Then I encrypt
$14^3 ≡ 8 \pmod {19}$

But I decrypt
$8 ^ {13} ≡ 8 \pmod {19}$

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT** My logic behind this is:

$m^e ≡ m' \pmod n$

if $e \cdot d≡1 \pmod n$ then

$m'^d ≡ m \pmod n$

Because $(m^e)^d = m^{e \cdot d} ≡ m^1 \pmod n$

Comment: $e \cdot d \equiv 1 \pmod {\varphi(n)}$, not $\pmod n$.

Comment: In your case $\varphi(n) = 18$ and 3 divides $18$, so you can't use $e=3$, because that'd make your encryption lossy and thus irreversible. $\operatorname{GCD}(e, \varphi(n) = 1$ is a necessary condition for RSA to work.

Comment: But if e*d≡1 (mod n)  then  $(m^e)^d = m^{e*d} ≡ m^1 \pmod n$

Comment: I know this will not make a good enryption because I am not choosing the right numbers, but just want to see why the maths don't work in my case

Comment: You can't just reduce the exponent modulo $n$. You need to reduce it modulo the order, $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: sorry I dont understand. So you are saying that this assumption is wrong: $if e*d≡1\pmod n then m^e≡m' \pmod n;  m'^d≡m \pmod n; because (m^e)^d=m^{e*d}≡m^1≡m \pmod n$

Comment: Can you elaborate why is that?  I saw my assumption in several sources, including page 4: http://www.mathaware.org/mam/06/Kaliski.pdf

Comment: I see... I think you just edited when I asked

Comment: Mmm.. I know you are right. But my problem I think it comes from the fact that $e * e^{-1} ≡1 \pmod n$ .... And if this is true I cannot see why my assumption is wrong, mathematically speaking.

Comment: Yes, I posted that before you edited. That's also why I know you are right. And if I calculate the inverse of 3 mod phi(19) ( = $\pmod {18}$) it doesn't exist. What I say is that the maths look right to me but there is something wrong about why the inverse doesn't work that I am not getting

Comment: So my assumption would be correct as:  $m^e ≡ m' \pmod n$ ; $m'^d ≡ m \pmod n$; $(m^e)^d = m^{e \cdot d} ≡ m^1 \pmod {\varphi(n)}$ ?

Comment: @user1156544: nope; you're mixing apples and spoons. c = m^e mod n, m = c^d = (m^e)^d = m^(ed) mod n, all using exponentiation; but with _no exponentiation_ ed = 1 or d = e^-1 mod phi(n) or mod lambda(n) which for prime n are the same and are the order of the multiplicative group mod n which is the group effectively underlying exponentiation done mod n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to follow as reference Burt Kaliski's [*The Mathematics of the RSA Public-Key Cryptosystem*](http://www.mathaware.org/mam/06/Kaliski.pdf), the question has the following issues:

- The question selects $n=19$ as a prime, rather than as the factor of two distinct primes $p$ and $q$ ($p=5$, $q=11$, $n=55$ in the reference); this is however not disastrous, and we'll adapt the reference by taking $n=p$ and ignoring $q$.
- The question uses $d$ such that $e\,d\equiv1\pmod n$, when nothing suggests that in the reference; the reference uses $e\,d\equiv1\pmod L$ with $L=\operatorname{lcm(p-1,q-1)}$, and with our adaptation that becomes $L=n-1$, thus the relation between $e$ and $d$ should be
  $$e\,d\equiv1\pmod{(n-1)}$$
- The question ignores the stated requirement that $e$ is relatively prime to $p-1$ and $q-1$ (meaning: $e$ shares no prime factor with either $p-1$ or $q-1$); with our adaptation this becomes that $e$ is relatively prime to $n-1$. It follows that $e=3$ is an invalid choice for $n=19$, since $3$ divides both $e=3$ and $n-1=18$.

If we keep $n=19$, we can use $e=5$, find $d$ such that $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{18}$, e.g. $d=11$. Then $c=m^e\bmod p=14^5\bmod19=10$, and $m'=c^d\bmod n=10^{11}\bmod19=14=m$, as expected.
Note: I use $c$ for the ciphertext as in the reference, and $m'$ for the the result of the decryption.

This is an application of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), which states that if $p$ is prime, then for all $m$ not divisible by $p$, it holds that $m^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$.

Notice that since we chosed $d$ with $e\,d\equiv1\pmod{(n-1)}$, it holds that $e\,d=k(n-1)+1$ for some integer $k$.

Now, the way we computed $m'$, it holds that
$$\begin{align}m'&\equiv c^d&\pmod n&&\text{ using }m'=c^d\bmod n\\
&\equiv{(m^e)}^d&\pmod n&&\text{ using }c=m^e\bmod n\\
&\equiv m^{e\,d}&\pmod n\\
&\equiv m^{k(n-1)+1}&\pmod n&&\text{ using }e\,d=k(n-1)+1\\
&\equiv {(m^{n-1})}^k\,m&\pmod n\\
&\equiv 1^k\,m&\pmod n&&\text{ using FLT}\\
&\equiv m&\pmod n\\
\end{align}$$
Note: when using the FLT, we rely on $n$ prime, and $m$ not divisible by $n$, which holds.

Since $m'=c^d\bmod n$ it holds that $0\le m'<n$. We have $0<m<n$ and $m'\equiv m\pmod n$, hence $m'=m$ <sub>Q.E.D.</sub>

---

An incorrect assumption made in the question's reasoning is that it would hold that $m^i\bmod n=m^{(i\bmod n)}\bmod n$; that's false in general, and a proof is given by the computations in the question.

What really holds is that $m^i\bmod n=m^{(i\bmod\lambda(n))}\bmod n$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), and $m$ is coprime with $n$ or $n$ is [square-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). The later holds in RSA. In the reference $n=p\,q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct primes, and $\lambda(n)=L=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

---

Standard notation, used in this answer (but not the reference, which omits parenthesis in the first notation): for $w>0$

- $u\equiv v\pmod w$ means that $w$ divides $u-v$
- $u=v\bmod w$ means that $w$ divides $u-v$ and $0\le u<w$.